# pyspark dataframe: fillna values of selected columns with different data types

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Following are legal:

```
df.fillna(0, subset=['a', 'b'])
or
df.fillna( { 'a':0, 'b':0 } )
```

**Question**: Is `df.fillna( { 'a':0, 'b':'2022-12-01'  } )` where column `a` as is of `float` type, and `b` is of `date` type, allowed, as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me

input schema

```
root
 |-- A: double (nullable = true)
 |-- D: date (nullable = true)
```

input df

```
+----+----------+
|   A|         D|
+----+----------+
| 0.0|      null|
|null|2009-01-02|
| 2.0|2009-01-05|
| 3.0|2009-01-06|
| 4.0|2009-01-07|
| 0.0|      null|
|null|2009-01-02|
| 2.0|2009-01-05|
| 3.0|2009-01-06|
| 4.0|2009-01-07|
+----+----------+
```

fillna

```
df=df.fillna({'A': 50, 'D': '2022-12-01'})
df.printSchema()
```

output schema

```
root
 |-- A: double (nullable = false)
 |-- D: date (nullable = true)
```

output df

```
+----+----------+
|   A|         D|
+----+----------+
| 0.0|2022-12-01|
|50.0|2009-01-02|
| 2.0|2009-01-05|
| 3.0|2009-01-06|
| 4.0|2009-01-07|
| 0.0|2022-12-01|
|50.0|2009-01-02|
| 2.0|2009-01-05|
| 3.0|2009-01-06|
| 4.0|2009-01-07|
+----+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.fillna.html) different data types are allowed but

> the replacement value must be an int, float, boolean, or string.